# Subjunctive with "sospechar"

Tags: verbos, subjuntivo

Do we use the subjunctive with *sospechar*, since it conveys doubt?

Like in the sentence

> I suspect that he was the murderer

would we say

> Sospecho que **fuera** el asesino

or would we say

> Sospecho que **era** el asesino

?

I'm not really sure, since the statement is affirmative (which might mean that we use the indicative), yet expresses doubt (typically meaning that we use the subjunctive)

Additionally, what about with the verb *suponer?* Does that verb follow a similar principle?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The verb "sospechar" is followed by indicative when it expresses more certainty (being similar to "creer"), and by subjunctive when it expresses more doubt (being similar to "imaginar"). I agree with [this site](http://www.hispanoteca.eu/Foro/ARCHIVO-Foro/Subjuntivo%20o%20indicativo%20con%20verbos%20de%20actividad%20mental.htm) (I have included the main ideas and examples containing "sospechar" and added the bolds) that the indicative is much more usual:

> Los verbos de percepción física o mental, cuando van en forma afirmativa piden indicativo en el verbo de la subordinada. Solo una lista muy limitada de ellos (parecer, admitir, conceder, aceptar, suponer, **sospechar**, imaginar, creer...) admiten el subjuntivo junto al indicativo. Pero **admiten subjuntivo en la subordinada solamente cuando se refieren a un marco ficticio, imaginado, supuesto, cuando significan más bien ‘imaginar’**.
>
> «De forma análoga a como el contenido de lo que se sueña admite dos interpretaciones, puede entenderse de dos maneras el contenido de lo que se sospecha, se supone o se imagina. **El modo que predomina en los complementos de estos verbos es el indicativo**:
>
> - Otros sospechaban que había sucedido algo extraordinario.
> - Me hace sospechar que ha perdido el favor con el emperador.
>
> **También se documenta el subjuntivo, aunque con frecuencia mucho menor**. Predominan en este uso, si bien no son los únicos posibles, los contextos en los que precede al verbo reductor un relativo que corresponde a la oración subordinada:
>
> - Menéndez Pidal sospecha que se trate de una fantasía.
>
> Cuando los contenidos que se presentan en estos casos se asimilan a las creencias o las asunciones, se construyen en indicativo, pero cuando se conciben como conjeturas, se expresan con subjuntivo. Ahora bien, debe precisarse que la doble interpretación de la que se habla (quizás resultado de una traslación del tipo CREENCIA > CONJETURA) no constituye una elección que el hablante lleve a cabo individualmente en cada caso particular, puesto que el uso de los verbos mencionados con subjuntivo es hoy minoritario, como se ha señalado.»
>
> [Real Academia Española: Nueva gramática de la lengua española. Madrid: 2009, § 25.4p]
>
> «**Los verbos que toleran el subjuntivo en la subordinada lo admiten sobre todo cuando conllevan la referencia a un marco ficticio o supuesto, es decir, cuando se acercan al sentido de imaginar, y mucho menos cuando suponen afirmación atenuada y se emparentan, por tanto, con creer.**
>
> En los siguientes ejemplos, *creer, imaginar, suponer, sospechar, parecer* vienen a significar ‘creer’, es decir, ‘en mi opinión, es verdad que’ (afirmación atenuada), y en ellos el subjuntivo les “suena” mal o no les “suena” del todo bien a muchos hablantes:
>
> ? Sospecho que tenga carta hoy.
>
> A modo de resumen, y como consejo práctico, aquellas personas que no dominan el español harían bien en utilizar siempre el indicativo con este tipo de verbos cuando van en forma afirmativa.»
>
> [Borrego, J., Asencio, J.G., Prieto, E.: El subjuntivo. Valores y usos. Madrid: SGEL, 1985, pp. 83-85]

Note about your verb **fuera**: If the subjunctive is applicable, a main verb in the present requires a subordinated verb in **present** subjunctive (not past subjunctive). Therefore, while *sospecho que sea el asesino* sounds fine, *sospecho que fuera...* does not. It's a mismatch.

The past subjunctive works perfectly if the main verb is in the past and the idea conveyed is that of a conjecture, not a belief:

- **Sospechaba** que **fuera** el asesino.

Comment: Please feel free to roll back if my edits don't feel right.